# Express.js close response

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, keep-alive

Is there a way to close a response? I can use `res.end()` but it doesn't actually close the socket.

What I want to achieve: I am writing a Java program which interfaces with the network, and I am writing a NodeJS server for this. Java code:

```
String line;
while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println("RES: "+line);
}
```

But this just keeps hanging. No end connection, still waiting for input from the socket.

Node:

```
exports.getAll = function (req, res) {
    res.set("Content-Type", "text/plain");
    res.set(200);
    res.send(..data..);
    res.end();
}
```

however `res.end()` does not close the connection. As said before, Java keeps thinking there will be something next so it is stuck in the `while` loop.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Solved by setting a HTTP header to close the connection instead of default keep-alive strategy.

```
res.set("Connection", "close");
```

Comment: is there any way I can hook it as default to all responses?

Comment: @AbhishekDeb if you create a middleware that sets the above header then it will work for all requests

Comment: Surely this just tells the remote side to close the connection.  You are not closing the connection if you are sending headers back in the response.

Comment: node might be (by default) keeping the connection open (keep-alive) strategy

Answer (score 17):

In case someone who really wants just to close the connection finds this, you can use [res.socket](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_socket) or [res.connection](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_connection) to get the [net.Socket](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_class_net_socket) object which comes with a [destroy](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_destroy_exception) method:

```
res.connection.destroy();
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to simulate a drop in network availability for automated tests without actually disabling the internet connection manually.