# Close connection instead of setting 'keep-alive'

Tags: node.js, express, keep-alive

I'm trying to disable the `keep-alive` setting in a very simple `express` app. I tried [the answer from someone doing the same in an older version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13554319/express-js-close-response):

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.set('Connection', 'close'); // attempting to override default (keep-alive)
    res.set('Proof', 'close');      // just to show that this should modify the header value
    res.send('hello');
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('Listening on port %d', server.address().port);
});
```

However, `Connection` is still set to `keep-alive`:

```
$ curl -D - http://my-test-site.com
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.4.7
Date: Sun, 11 May 2014 08:07:51 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 5
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: Express
Proof: close
ETag: "907060870"

hello%
```

How can I change `keep-alive` to `close`?

#### Versions

node 0.10.8
express 4.1.1

Comment: Have you tried `res.set("KeepAlive", false)`?  Here are the docs for Node http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_setkeepalive_enable_initialdelay ... I'm not very familiar with express.

Comment: res.set('KeepAlive'...) is wrong answer. it set a new header filed which name is "KeepAlive" and the value is "false"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works fine for me. I test it localhost the same version.

```
$ curl -D - 127.0.0.1:3000
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Connection: close
Proof: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 5
ETag: "907060870"
Date: Sun, 11 May 2014 08:52:32 GMT

hello%
```

I see that you may use `nginx` to proxy. Like below:

`client--nginx proxy--real server`

I guess that you should disable `keep-alive` in nginx config file.