# Node.js / How handle connection leak?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I wrote a server application in Node.js.

When I do `lsof -p 10893` (10893 is the pid of my Node.js application), I get this:

```
node    10893 root   19u  IPv4 (num) 0t0    TCP ip-X.X.X.X->ip-X-X-X.X:45403 (ESTABLISHED)
node    10893 root   19u  IPv4 (num) 0t0    TCP ip-X.X.X.X->ip-X-X-X.X:58416(ESTABLISHED)
```

This connections are hold and never closed, just when I restart my application.

I have the following code in node.js, which as I understand, should handle this issue:

```
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.setTimeout(120000);
    res.status(500).send('Unexpected error');
});
```

But these connection are still appears, even after 120000 ms.

How can I fix it?

Comment: What do you expect to accomplish?

Comment: @satchcoder: That this connection will be closed after 120000 ms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty sure this is a Keep-Alive issue. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13554319/express-js-close-response) and it's answer for details, but the gist is:

```
res.set("Connection", "close");
```

If you want that behavior for all your connections, then add it as a middleware above your routes/router:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.set("Connection", "close");
    next();
});
```

Also, if you want to time out the socket itself, it's a bit trickier:

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');

var app = express();
var svr = http.createServer(app);

svr.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.setTimeout(120000, function () {
        this.end();
    });
});

// other middleware / routes here

app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(500).send('Unexpected error');
});

svr.listen(PORT);
```

**EDIT**:

Just noticed that your function is an error handler middleware (due to the presence of the `err` parameter). This means that the timeout would only have been set if there was an error, and not if the request completed successfully.

Comment: There is no impact to change the strategy from Keep-alive to connection close?

Comment: There are ramifications, it depends on what your app is doing. Is the client a browser? Is it an API where the client is going to be making many requests to the service in a row? In those cases Keep-Alive would be better, and you can rely on the timeout.