# node.js page keep loading when using res.send();

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

**(When I run same code on ubuntu with node 4.2.6. I don't see this problem. )**
I found some has similar problem: [Express.js close response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13554319/express-js-close-response)

==============problem description=========================
I encountered a very strange problem.
In my [Express](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.send) project, I am using [passport](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport) package.
As long as I signed in myself, then every page will keep loading for 2 minutes. 
If I am not logged in, I found pages behave normally.

```
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('index', {
        title: 'FASIDS',
        activePage:'Home',
        isAuthenticated: req.isAuthenticated(),
        user: processReqUser(req.user)
    }, function (err, html) {
        if (err) {
            next(err);
            return;
        }
        res.send(html);
    });
});
```

I have to substitute `res.send(html)` with `res.end(html)` to make my code behaves normally in both situations ("signed in" or "not signed in").

Really have no idea how to deal with it. Please help.

Additionally, please refer my [processedPassport.js](https://github.com/bovetliu/FASIDS_proto/blob/master/components/processedPassport.js) to see how I am handling authentication.

The passport is used in app.js as following:

```
...irrelevant code..

var passport = require('./components/processedPassport.js').addPassport(app, db_models);

...irrelevant code....
```

For reference, I included screenshots
Following pic shows a loading time of 2 mins
[image: screenshots showing 2 min long loading time]

Following pic shows request and response headers
[image: response header]

Comment: Can you post how you handle authentication in passport.js itself? It seems your code is doing everything correctly in the route handling.

Comment: @ngoctranfire please refer https://github.com/bovetliu/FASIDS_proto/blob/master/components/processedPassport.js to see my authentication code.

Comment: If `res.end()` works, what exactly is the problem? `res.end()` both sends a response and ends the request object, which should be good behaviour (unless you want a persistent connection?).

Comment: @AkshatMahajan The only difference I observed is that, res.end() will include Transfer-Encoding:chunked after I logged in. Using res.send() will not include this header field, instead, I will find"Date:Sat, 02 Apr 2016 15:22:56 GMT
ETag:W/"9b-jJAq3AISRHi+ZUZBsrt/Mw" in response header