# How to close HTTP connection in node.js using Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server-sent-events

I use node.js (Express) with server-sent events. I would like to close the event stream by closing the sse HTTP connection. Given the folllwing function:

```
router.get('/sse', function (req, res) {

});
```

how can this be achieved?

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13554590/1176331) could be your solution as answered by @Mikael.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

use this

```
res.end();
```

and it will work to close connection

Comment: this ends response, but doesn't close TCP connection.

Answer (score 15):

## How to hang up in ExpressJS

### Ⅰ. End the response, keeping the socket connection alive.

```js
response.end();
```

### Ⅱ. “Could you please hang up first?”

Request the client to initiate the TCP socket connection termination sequence.

```
response.set("Connection", "close"); // Note: this is an HTTP header.
```

### Ⅲ. Gently close the socket connection.

**“Hey, I’ll be hanging up now, ’kay?”**

[image: TCP connection termination sequence]

```
response.connection.end();
```

> #### [`socket.end([data[, encoding]][, callback])`](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_end_data_encoding_callback)
>
> Half-closes the socket. i.e., it sends a `FIN` packet. It is possible the server will still send some data.
>
> See `writable.end()` for further details.

### Ⅳ. Just hang up on the client aggressively. No `FIN` packet, even.

```
response.connection.destroy();
```

> #### [`socket.destroy([error])`](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_destroy_error)
>
> Ensures that no more I/O activity happens on this socket. Destroys the stream and closes the connection.
>
> See `writable.destroy()` for further details.

Answer (score 4):

Selected answer is incorrect, res.end() ends the response and writes to the socket. But it doesn't close the TCP connection.

You need to get the underlying connection from the res object and call end on it to close it.

res.connection.end();