# How to disable keep-alive in node server

Tags: node.js, express, keep-alive

I am developing an application backend based on `node.js` server and express, the application is receiving an external flux from an `apache` server that require a "keep alive " disabled

So I tried to disable the option buy req.setSocketKeepAlive(false);

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);
var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
server.keepAliveTimeout(0)
```

but it doesnt work.

Do you have any ideas how to solve this issue ?

Comment: Set the `keepAliveTimeout` configuration option on the http server instance. [See the docs](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_keepalivetimeout).

Comment: @RobertRossmann I already tried to, but it doesnt work since it's linked to express app

Answer (score 3):

Although not ideal, setting the `Connection` header to `close` in a middleware can help you.

[Express.js close response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13554319/express-js-close-response)